# If JSON represents the 'object', what represents the 'class'?

Tags: json

JSON appears to be a nice way to represent a complex data structure in plain text. If we think of this complex data structure as analogous to an OOP object - an instance of a class - then is there a commonly used JSON-like format that represents the class itself (just the data part - forget methods)? Can JSON itself be used for this?

To put it another way, if JSON encodes name-value pairs, what should I use if I want to encode only the names?

The reason I want this is that I am designing a protocol to use with jQuery (to which I am a complete novice by the way). The client will communicate to the server the structure of the JSON object it wants back, and the server will return a JSON object of that structure with the values added.

The key point is that it is the *client* that is in full control of what data fields (name-value pairs) the server returns. It's a bit different from all the examples of jQuery that I've found so far on the web where the client makes a request (which usually includes a very limited set of parameters, if any) and the server makes the decision as to what fields to return in the JSON reply.

(Obviously, what the client asks for must be congruent with the server's data model; if the server has an array of widgets each with its own price, the client can't ask for an array of prices each with its own widget.)

This must be a common problem, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I want to adopt a solution that is already in common use across the web.

**Edit**
I just found [JSON Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Schema). This is *not* what I am looking for. It contains way more than I need.

**Edit**
I'm looking more for a 'this is how it is usually done' answer, rather than a 'you could try…' answer. (I can invent dozens of possible answers myself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for **Partial Response**.

[RESTful API Design: can your API give developers just the information they need?](http://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_can_your_api_give_developers_just_the_information/) explains it all and gives examples from LinkedIn, Facebook, and Google. Google and Facebook both have similar approaches. Here's how Lie Ryan's example would look using Google's approach:

```
url?fields=status,result(color,price)
```

Since Google and Facebook are behind this, I would not be surprised to see this become a de facto standard.

In my case I am likely to run into a length limitation on the URL and so have to use POST instead, but this is an excellent starting point for me.

Answer (score 1):

To encode only names within JSON, you could use a key/value pair where the key is either the class name or just a key named 'values' - with the value being an array of strings that are the names to be returned by the server. For example:

```
{ 'class_name' : [ "name1", "name2", "name3" ] }
```

The server can then either detect the class name from the key used and return the supplied values for the names in the array if the class supports it or ignore if it does not.

Comment: I see. Yes, I think that will work. For a second level of hierarchy I seem to need to insert a new object instead of a string in the array. My original question remains though: Is this how this problem is usually solved 'out there'?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking more for a 'this is how it is usually done' answer

There is no single "correct" way to do what you want. Many people have their implementation. It depends on various factors -- what you want to do, where you want to do, how efficiently you want it to do?

---

For simple structures I would prefer and suggest the answer given by @dbr9979.

For nested structures, you can have nested arrays. Something like:

```
{
    "nestedfield1": {
        "nestedfield11":["nestedfield111", "nestedfield112"],
        "nestedfield12":["nestedfield121", "nestedfield122"],
        "__SIMPLE_FIELDS__": ["simplefield13", "simplefield14"]
    }
}
```

The point is, if the key is `__SIMPLE_FIELDS__`, the value is an array of simple fields (string, numbers etc..), else the key stands for the key in the object.

---

For something more complex, what I would suggest is you have predefined structures, that both the server and the client know of. This is particularly useful when you have to make multiple identical requests. Assign some unique number for each of them. Something like:

```
1 => <the structure above>
2 => ["simplefield1", "simplefield2" ..]
3 => etc .. etc
```

The server stores the above structure and the relevant number in the database or something. And now, as it may be obvious by now, client sends across the id of the required structure, and the server responds in the appropriate fashion.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you meant by this:

> the client that is in full control of what data fields (name-value pairs) the server returns.

is like the difference between `SELECT * FROM Bags` and `SELECT color, price FROM Bag` in SQL. Am I interpreting you correctly?

You could query with:

```
{
    'resource': 'Bag',
    'field_names': ['color', 'price']
}
```

which will return the response:

```
{
    'status': 'success',
    'result': [
        {'color': 'red', 'price': 50},
        {'color': 'blue', 'price': 45},
    ]
}
```

most likely though, you may not actually need your request to be a JSON object; I've seen implementations where the field names is taken from the query string, like http://foo.com/bag?fields=color,price